# Discord.net Find out if someone has a role

Tags: discord.net

Hey how I check if some have a role with role id
like I want to know if user have role `713478343994900590`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your guild user object you can do

```cs
If (guildUser.Roles.Any(role => role.id = 713478343994900590)) {
    //code here if role exists
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to cast the SocketUser to a SocketGuildUser. Then just iterate through each of its roles and check for the id. I like to use Linq for that. This should work:

```cs
    var guildUser = Context.User as SocketGuildUser;

    if(guildUser.Roles.Where(role => role.Id == 713478343994900590).FirstOrDefault() != null)
    {
                //do something
    }
```